# What am I riddle

Tags: riddle

Here it is-

> I am owned from birth until death,
>   never borrowed nor stolen can I be.
>   Yet I am most often used by others,
>   and rarely by the one who possesses me.
>
> What am I?
>   
> <sub>— from [The Adventurer’s Guild to Dragons](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Adventurer_s_Guide_to_Dragons_and_Wh.html?id=iUTTDQAAQBAJ)</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it

> your name?

I am owned from birth until death,

> your name is yours from birth until death

never borrowed nor stolen can I be.

> your name is yours and can't be borrowed or stolen (unlike your identity)

Yet I am most often used by others,

> people use your name when communicating with youi

and rarely by the one who possesses me.

> rarely do you call yourself by your own name.

Comment: I thought it was an anime..

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> your name? In Western Civilization, one usually keeps it his whole life, but he/she almost never uses it - it's used by others.

Comment: Ah, you beat me by 5 seconds. I've deleted by answer.

Comment: haha ok. I saw this at just the right time

Comment: It's definitely correct: https://bit.ly/2EXJFsw

Answer (score 1):

It could be

> a social security number